# Twitter bootstrap & IE8 and lower

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

So I know Twitter bootstrap & IE8 have issues because of the media queries, and it ends up rendering the columns at 100% width. I read that adding in respond.js & html5shiv.js will fix the problems, which I have done but the problem still occurs. I call them after the css, all locally. IE7 has the same problem and IE5, well that's just one big ugly mess. I know I'm probably doing something really stupid wrong, but yeah, hope someone can help me out!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/images/favicon.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/images/icon-72.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">

        <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
        <?php wp_head(); ?>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/script.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/respond.min.js"></script>

    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Hm, I was thinking maybe I need the bootstrap css in the same folder as the js?

Comment: You can make bootstrap compatible with IE8, it is incompatible with anything lower. You need to support IE5?! I haven't had to support that in a decade. You have my sympathies.

Comment: Hard to say much from just this. Are the files present in the browser?

Comment: View the source of the rendered page in your browser, what are the paths to respond.js and html5shiv.js? Do they correspond with their actual location.

Comment: If you view source in Firefox or Chrome you can simply click the file links to check them.

Comment: I don't have to support IE5? I was under some impression I had to support everything in existence. Yes they all link to the right location.

Comment: Okay now it suddenly works in IE8, but not IE7. In IE7 they aren't full width anymore. They are the correct width but not in the layout they should be, its ignoring the rule of the rows now instead. Is supporting IE7 important?

Comment: You should try and support the browsers that a significant number of users are using to visit your site(s). If you have a very small number of users visiting using IE7/8/9 then consider not bothering to support them. You can also encourage users to update to the latest version of IE, Chrome etc on your help/support page if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind that some companies bought thousands of PC's for their employees with windows XP or Vista and they won't upgrade until it's fesable to do so,and yes there are millions of people using old IE at work and need to see actual working content when they browse,if your site doesnt work,you lose them.